# Python: querying a list of results while processes are finishing

Tags: python

I am using the twitter API to capture the number of times a user has tweeted. I would like to get access to the list of results before all of the process have completed

```
def get_status_count(twitter_handle, output): 

while True: 
    try: 
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_keys, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        client = tweepy.API(auth)
        twitter_handle = twitter_handle
        user = client.get_user(screen_name = twitter_handle)
        timeline = user.timeline()

        status = timeline[0]
        json_str = json.dumps(status._json)
        json_dict = json.loads(json_str)

        json_user_dict =  json_dict['user'] 
        total_tweets = json_user_dict['statuses_count']

        output.put(total_tweets)

        break

    except tweepy.error.TweepError as e:
        print "In the except method"
        print e
        time.sleep(5)
```

I want to check twitter multiple times to see if the status count has changed. I've implemented this code.

```
processes = [mp.Process(target=get_status_count, args=('gregcharte', 
output)) for x in range(10)]


# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()


# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()

results = [output.get() for p in processes]
print results
```

which gives me a list `[80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80]`. How can I instead get the list after each process finishes. For instance

`[80]
[80, 80]
[80, 80, 80]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to multiprocessing.

Comment: put your print statement inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need multiple processes to manage the data, you can call a function from within try block that will have all the business logic on what you want and what you don't want.

A example of what that would look like is below:

```
# Access Tokens etc would be constants or preferably env variables... 
# .....

TWEET_DATA = []

def init_tweepy():
     auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_keys, consumer_secret)
     auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
     return tweepy.API(auth)

def add_new_tweet_data(data):
    # Do your checks in here...
    TWEET_DATA.append(data)

def listen_to_stream(twitter_handle):

    # Tweepy setup.
    client = init_tweepy() 
    user = client.get_user(screen_name = twitter_handle)

    while True: 
        try:
            # Grab user's timeline data.
            timeline = user.timeline()

        except Exception as e:
           print(e)
           time.sleep(5)

        else:

          # Data marshalling
            status = timeline[0]
            json_str = json.dumps(status._json)
            json_dict = json.loads(json_str)

            # Accessing necessary keys.
            json_user_dict =  json_dict['user'] 
            total_tweets = json_user_dict['statuses_count']

            # Append new data.
            add_new_tweet_data(total_tweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to print each piece of the list as it builds all you need to do is to put your print statement up into the loop. It would look something like this:

```
results = []
for p in processes:
    results = results.append([output.get])
    print results
```

I haven't tested that you may need to tweak it but that should do it
also I would look into multithreading for checking the status of something while running